# Change default player to JW Player

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I ‘d like to play all my previews video links only with JW Player .
I install jw player & jw player 7 for wp. but it can affect only in new posts!
how can I replace it with the default WordPress video player?

Comment: What type of shortcode does Jw player add to posts ?

Comment: i used this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/simple-shortcode-for-jw-player-7/… [jw7-video]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a little script to apply on demand (uncomment delete_option line to do it again), place it in functions.php.

This script will find any posts and replace an old shortcode tag by a new one.

It uses `get_shortcode_regex()` and `has_shortcode` the shortcode to detect needs to be a registered shortcode (add via add_shortcode(), see `dummy_shortcode()` at the end).

```
add_action('init', 'se_40815010');

function se_40815010(){

    if(get_option('se_40815010') == true){
        return;
    }

    $old_tag = 'video';
    $new_tag = 'jw7-video';

    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>'post',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_status' => 'any'
    );

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    foreach($posts->posts as $post){
        if(has_shortcode($post->post_content, $old_tag)){

            $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

            if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
                && array_key_exists( 2, $matches )
                && in_array( $old_tag, $matches[2] ) ) {

                    $new_content = str_replace($matches[2][0], $new_tag, $post->post_content);

                    $post_update = array(
                        'ID'=> $post->ID,
                        'post_content'=> $new_content
                    );

                    $update = wp_update_post($post_update, true);

                    if($update && !is_wp_error($update)){
                        $result .= 'Post ID '.$post->ID.', gallery shortcode modified.</br>';
                    }
                    else{
                        $error_string = $update->get_error_message();
                        $result .= '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string .'</p></div>';
                    }
             }
        }
    }

    wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), 'Shortcode replace', $result);

    update_option('se_40815010', true);
}
// delete_option('se_40815010');
```

With `has_shortcode()`, the shortcode needs to be registered with `add_shortcode()` to be recognized. We create a fake shortcode and the old tag we are looking will be recognized.

```
if(get_option('se_40815010')!= true){
    add_shortcode('fakegallery', 'dummy_shortcode');
}
function dummy_shortcode($content){
    return 'hello world';
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What kind of "became down", no error message, a time out,  ? I don't exactly know why but sometimes there's no need to close php tag at the end of the functions.php.

Comment: So remove it, it's impossible to know, you need to enable the debug mode.

Comment: can you share your site link ?

Comment: ' PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /......./functions.php on line 1660  ) '' syntax error, unexpected end of file in ....../functions.php on line 436'

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo ! if(get_option('se_40815010') == true){ . I forgot to close parenthesis after "se_40815010'".

Comment: @Benoti : have you used jwplayer plugin for wordpress? - https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403714-jw6-wordpress-plugin-reference

Comment: I did, but not yet.

Comment: @Benoti it doesn't work! and this time I dont have log file! it didnt create it at all.

Comment: @Benoti `code:  if(get_option('se_40815010)!= true){
    add_shortcode("fakegallery", 'dummy_shortcode');
}
function dummy_shortcode($content){
    return 'hello world';
}      `  is it ture ? I check it by [phpcodechecker](http://phpcodechecker.com/) and get some errors.

Comment: still typo I think, I edit the answer with a new copy, this must work ! (it works with me).

Comment: Sorry, everything is working well for me. Maybe you need to delete_option ? or you can change the option number, if it's a new one, the script would run again.

Comment: Are you still facing issue ? @Mohammad

Comment: what theme are you using ? @Mohammad

Comment: It works for me, you can run the script without the theme. Create a file called "shortcode_replace.php" place it at the wp root. At the top copy this : define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require ('wp-blog-header.php'); Add the function only (add_shortcode() and related function if need). in the file, add, se_40815010(); to trigger the function.